# Kivy Пишет что модуь не найден

Tags: python, kivy, app

В киви когда прописываю python а затем from kivy.app import App

выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Comment: А вы точно установили kivy?

Comment: pip install kivy